# fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c

I got this error when I executed `g++ mycode.cpp`, and this .cpp file include a line `#include<openssl/rsa.h>`. Now, I know the error's reason, and I have tow plan to resolve it:

1. I can add the `openssl` path to `/etc/profile`,
2. or I also can copy openssl folder to /usr/include, so I did the first plan, like this:

---

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/mylib

export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

(my openssl folder's path is /mylib/openssl)

and I got this error again.

Then I try second plan, and it passed complie,(like this /usr/include/openssl).

Now, my problem is,

why the header ("openssl/rsa.h") can be found under `/usr/include/` but can not be found under `/mylib/`, even I had add the path(/mylib) to `/etc/profile`?

Comment: Such info is often found in the [toolchain docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To install OpenSSL on Debian, Ubuntu, or other derivative versions:

$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

To install the OpenSSL development kit on Fedora, CentOS, or RHEL:

$ sudo yum install openssl-devel

After installation, try to recompile the program.

Comment: I know you advice would be work, but now I want to ask is that why the header cannot be found when I added the path /mylib(openssl belong) to /etc/profile

Comment: e... This is my fault ! I simply guess put the folder to the path /usr/include would be OK. finally resolved it in the way you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall the library using the `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```